# android fetch string from Json url

Tags: android, json, url, fetch

I have this url json link:
http://api.aladhan.com/timingsByAddress/06-06-2020?address=Jeddah,SaudiArabia&method=1

, and I want to fetch some strings from it, I saw some tutorials and tried working on it but it always show empty screen without any error from logcat,

I dont know if the problem is from the code or from the url,

here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RequestQueue req;
TextView fajerText,aserText,maghrebText;
String fajer,aser,maghreb;
String url="http://api.aladhan.com/timingsByAddress/06-06-2020?address=Jeddah,SaudiArabia&method=8";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    req= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    fajerText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_fajr);
    aserText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_aser);
    maghrebText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_maghreb);

    sendjsonrequest();

}

public void sendjsonrequest(){

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                fajer = response.getString("code");
                aser = response.getString("status");
                maghreb = response.getString("data");

                fajerText.setText(fajer);
                aserText.setText(aser);
                maghrebText.setText(maghreb);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    req.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 "data": {
    "timings": {
      "Fajr": "04:15",
      "Sunrise": "05:40",
      "Dhuhr": "12:22",
      "Asr": "15:40",
      "Sunset": "19:04",
      "Maghrib": "19:04",
      "Isha": "20:29",
      "Imsak": "04:05",
      "Midnight": "00:22"
    }
```

**Don't**

```
 maghreb = response.getString("data");
```

Your **`data`** is ***JSONObject***. You should use `getJSONObject()` instead of `getString()`.

> [**`getJSONObject(String name)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#getJSONObject(java.lang.String)). Returns the value mapped by name if it
>   exists and is a JSONObject , or throws otherwise

**Do**

```
 JSONObject data      = response.getJSONObject("data");
 JSONObject timings   = data.getJSONObject("timings");
 String     fair      = timings.getString("Fajr");
```